# Python ZipFile does not compress as small as zip in terminal

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I have a large amount of data I am writing to a zip file using the following code:

```py
import json
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED

with ZipFile(out_path, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED) as z_file:
    z_file.writestr(filename, json.dumps(data))
```

The result is a file that is 3.1 MB. When I uncompress it with `unzip`, I get a new file that is 33 MB. Then, when I recompress it using `zip`, I get a file that is 2.1 MB.

Why are the two compressed files different sizes?

I am using a Mac, thus I am using the Mac version of `zip` Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP. And I am using Python 3.9.4. The man page for `zip` says it uses the deflate algorithm by default, which I believe is the same algorithm I used in the Python code above.

I did see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57713248/why-zipfile-does-not-give-the-same-output-zip-file-size-as-zip), but their issue was that the file was not compressing at all because they were using a ZipInfo object. My file does compress, but just not as small as with `zip`, and I'm not using a ZipInfo object.

## Update

I ran some tests to see if the difference was caused by the `compresslevel` option. The man page for `zip` says the default compress level is 6. So I used Python's `ZipFile` and the `zip` command to compress the same file, first without a compress level value (the default), then by explicitly setting it to 6, and then 9.

In my program, I am generating the data and then writing it to a file. I wanted to see if there was a difference to compressing data stored in memory versus compressing data read from a file, so I also used `ZipFile` to compress the data in both of these scenarios.

I also tried using `shutil` for good measure. It doesn't appear to have an option for compress level, so I just have the default result.

Here are the results.

| Zip Method | Default | Level 6 | Level 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unzipped | 33M | N/A | N/A |
| `ZipFile` Generated Data | 3.1M | 3.1M | 2.9M |
| `ZipFile` From File | 3.1M | 2.1M | 2.9M |
| `zip` From File | 2.1 M | 4.2M | 2.3M |
| `shutil` From File | 2.1M | N/A | N/A |

I find it very strange that 1) none of the results between the `ZipFile` and `zip` match for the same compress level, and 2) that just explicitly setting the compress level to 6 for `zip` (which is supposedly the default) causes the file to be twice as large.

Any more thoughts as to what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried compressing the default data without converting it to json?

Comment: `data` is a dictionary. It needs to be serialized somehow before I can write it to a file. I don't think i should matter if it is JSON or not, since I am simply decompressing and recompressing the same file.

Comment: Perhaps it is compresslevel. The doc reads: The compresslevel parameter controls the compression level to use when writing files to the archive. When using ZIP_STORED or ZIP_LZMA it has no effect. When using ZIP_DEFLATED integers 0 through 9 are accepted (see zlib for more information). When using ZIP_BZIP2 integers 1 through 9 are accepted (see bz2 for more information).

Comment: @user7571491 The `compresslevel` doesn't appear the be the entire problem. I updated my question with some results from testing different values of `compresslevel`. They are rather confusing.

Comment: Trevin Avery: please rewrite those results as a [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support), with compresslevel as a column, and zip method as row.

Comment: @smci I forget that you make make tables. I updated it as you requested.